# MarkLogic Node.js Sort on "last-modified"

Tags: node.js, marklogic

I want to sort the documents by metadata property "**last-modified**". I have already created element-range-index on "last-modified" and also enabled option "**maintain last modified**" in Admin Panel for the database.But, when I run below statement in Node.js

```
return db.documents.query(
        qb.where().orderBy(qb.sort("last-modified")).slice(from, length)).result();
```

I am getting below error. Please help?

```
 Error { [Error: query documents: response with invalid 400 status]
  message: 'query documents: response with invalid 400 status',
  statusCode: 400,
  body:
   { errorResponse:
      { statusCode: 400,
        status: 'Bad Request',
        messageCode: 'SEARCH-BADORDERBY',
        message: 'SEARCH-BADORDERBY: (err:FOER0000) Indexes are required to supp
ort element, element-attribute, json-property, or field sort specifications.' }
} }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: *clarified fragments explanation; fixed examples*

The `last-modified` property (controlled by the `maintain last modified` setting) is **not** stored in the *document* itself, but in the *document properties*, which is a metadata fragment associated with each document. In the MarkLogic Node.js API, you can constrain queries to the document or the document properties with [`qb.documentFragment()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/jsdoc/queryBuilder.html#documentFragment) or [`qb.propertiesFragment()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/jsdoc/queryBuilder.html#propertiesFragment).

However, you can only sort by aspects of the data you are returning: by default, the document itself. You can specify that your query return either `documents` or `properties` using [`qb.fragmentScope()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/jsdoc/queryBuilder.html#fragmentScope).

*Note: Document properties are stored as XML in the `http://marklogic.com/xdmp/property` namespace, so your element-range-index must also use that namespace.*

Here's how you would get the 10 most-recent document properties:

```
return db.documents.query(
  qb.where(
    qb.fragmentScope('properties')
  ).orderBy(
    qb.sort(
      qb.element(qb.qname('http://marklogic.com/xdmp/property', 'last-modified')),
      'descending'
    )
  ).slice(1, 10))
.result();
```

You could further restrict these results by any query matching the document itself with `qb.documentFragment()`:

*assuming an `int` range index on `test`:*

```
return db.documents.query(
  qb.where(
    qb.fragmentScope('properties'),
    qb.documentFragment(
      qb.range( qb.element('test'), '<', 20 )
    )
  ).orderBy(
    qb.sort(
      qb.element(qb.qname('http://marklogic.com/xdmp/property', 'last-modified')),
      'descending'
    )
  ).slice(1, 10))
.result();
```

Finally, if you want to then get the documents themselves, and not their properties, you could make a request to `db.documents.read()`, with the document URIs retrieved by the query:

*Note: the following examples use lodash/underscore*

```
return db.documents.query(
  qb.where(
    qb.fragmentScope('properties'),
    qb.documentFragment(
      qb.range( qb.element('test'), '<', 20 )
    )
  ).orderBy(
    qb.sort(
      qb.element(qb.qname('http://marklogic.com/xdmp/property', 'last-modified')),
      'descending'
    )
  ).slice(1, 10))
.result(function(documents) {
  db.documents.read(
    _.map(documents, 'uri')
  ).result(function(documents) {
    _.each(documents, function(doc) { console.log(doc.content); })
  });
});
```

Alternately, your application could maintain a `last-modified` property directly in your documents, in which case your query can be much simpler:

```
return db.documents.query(
  qb.where(
    qb.range( qb.element('test'), '<', 20 )
  ).orderBy(
    qb.sort( qb.element('last-modified'), 'descending' )
  ).slice(1, 10))
.result(function(documents) {
  _.each(documents, function(doc) { console.log(doc.content); })
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Please also note that I am reading XML documents from Node.js

Comment: Is there an error, or do they appear to not be sorted? Also, did you update your element-range-index config to use the properties namespace?

Comment: @Vishal.Net, I believe the above is what you want, with a minor adjustment to the contents of orderBy. The final result you want I believe to be 

`return db.documents.query(
  qb.where(
    qb.fragmentScope('properties')
  ).orderBy(
    qb.sort(qb.element(qb.qname('http://marklogic.com/xdmp/property', 'last-modified')),'descending')
  ).slice(from, length)
).result();`

Comment: Yes thanks the above query works. But it only returns list of document properties. But I want the documents [actual content] sorted by last-modified date?

Comment: thanks @justdewit!, I've fleshed out my answer (and actually tested my queries ;)). @vishal-net, I've added an example that shows how you could get documents from document properties.

Comment: hello, your answer is correct. the only trade-off is : when we do  db.documents.read( _.map(documents, 'uri') ); it does not return documents in the sequence corresponding to URI. So a re-sort needs to be done in memory but that's OK (Please correct me if I am wrong). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Based on my testing, the order **is** preserved. (That also follows from the [implementation](https://github.com/marklogic/node-client-api/blob/36cb139c6064416db39ef35e93bd4e0abe8ac71b/lib/documents.js#L324); note that the array of URIs is map'ed and then joined, preserving the order of `uri` URL params sent to the `/v1/documents` REST API endpoint)